# Password authentication failed when trying to run django application on server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have downloaded postgresql as well as django and python but when I try running the command  "python manage.py runserver"   it gives me an error saying "Fatal: password authentication failed for user" .   I am trying to run it locally but am unable to figure out how to get past this issue.

I was able to connect to the server in pgAdmin but am still getting password authentication error message

Comment: Have you configured the database settings on the app settings?

Comment: You mean the settings.py file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the password used to connect to your local Database, and this can be done, modifying your setting.py file in "DATABASES" object